# Как убрать toggle эффект?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, плагин

Возник вопрос, о том как возможно убрать `toggle` в коде, этот плагин установлен в `WordPress` называется он `olevmedia-shortcodes`.

Моя главная задача чтобы не было `аккордеон` эфекта при клике на кнопку. 
Какие есть варианты решения данного вопроса?

Сейчас картина выглядик так [image: при нажатии срабатывает toggle, но не должен]

Вот код:

```
omShortcodes.modules.toggle = {
init: function() {

    jQuery('.omsc-accordion .omsc-toggle').addClass('omsc-in-accordion').find('.omsc-toggle-title').click(function(){

        var $toggle=jQuery(this).parent();

        if($toggle.hasClass('omsc-expanded')) {
            $toggle.removeClass('omsc-expanded');
            $toggle.find('.omsc-toggle-inner').slideUp(300);
            return false;
        }

        var $acc=$toggle.parents('.omsc-accordion');
        if(!$acc.hasClass('omsc-multiopen'))
            $acc.find('.omsc-toggle.omsc-expanded').removeClass('omsc-expanded').find('.omsc-toggle-inner').slideUp(300);

        $toggle.find('.omsc-toggle-inner').slideDown(300,function(){
            var h=jQuery(this).parent().height();
            var pos=jQuery(this).parent().find('.omsc-toggle-title').offset();
            var scroll=jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            var wh=jQuery(window).height();
            if(pos.top < scroll || (pos.top > scroll && pos.top+h > scroll+wh))
                jQuery('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: pos.top+'px' }, 200);
        }).find('iframe[src*="maps.google"]').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).attr('src',jQuery(this).attr('src'));
        });
        $toggle.addClass('omsc-expanded');

    });

    jQuery('.omsc-toggle').not('.in-accordion').find('.omsc-toggle-title').click(function(){

        var $toggle=jQuery(this).parent();

        var $inner=$toggle.find('.omsc-toggle-inner');
        if(!$inner.length)
            return false;
        if($inner.is(':animated'))
            return false;

        $toggle.toggleClass('omsc-expanded');
        $inner.slideToggle(300);
        if($toggle.hasClass('omsc-expanded')) {
            $inner.find('iframe[src*="maps.google"]').each(function(){
                jQuery(this).attr('src',jQuery(this).attr('src'));
            });
        }

        return false;
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Я полагаю достаточно убрать с элемента эти классы `.omsc-accordion .omsc-toggle`. Или один, который отвечает именно за аккордеон эффект

Comment: @alexoander спасибо большое, получилось!